# arrayfun not equal to a specific character MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I know how to implement not equal with a loop but I would prefer to do that with an arrayfun function.

Let's assume that I have a matrix with elements -1 and 1 only, randomly generated. 
Where m = 10 and n = 4.

```
% Generate from a uniformly random sample
X = ones(m,n) - floor(rand(m,n)*2)*2;
Y = ones(m,1) - floor(rand(m,1)*2)*2;
```

My thought was to create something like this:

```
B = arrayfun(@(x) x~=1,X);
```

apparently doesn't work. My iteration is to check if every element from X is not qual to a specific character, and if that statement is true then to return value of one, else a value of zero.
Any thoughts? Thanks

PS: The code works, I just did a mistake with different notations in my program. Thanks @Suever for the notice.

PS. I will keep updating this with my progress

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `arrayfun` for this.  To check that every element of `X` is not equal to specific value `n` do this:

```
all(X ~= n)
```

`X ~= n` returns a logical array. `all()` checks if all elements of the logical array are `true`.

Besides being simpler, this approach is more efficient than `arrayfun`. It uses native compiled code, while `arrayfun` uses the matlab interpreter to apply a function to every element of the array.

Comment: @Dima `all()` works as you explained **only on vectors**, for arrays of more than 1d the following behavior happens: "_`B = all(A)` tests along the first array dimension of `A` whose size does not equal `1`, and determines if the elements are all nonzero or logical `1` (true). In practice, `all` is a natural extension of the logical AND operator._". To get what you meant, one should use `all( X(:) ~= n)`.